# after crypt password,validation not function well

Tags: php

now i using this code to crypt my password on database,it function when login or validation.
But it only valid the first 7 character.
let say my password is miow12345, but i can just type in miow123 or miow12312q... to login

```
$pas = crypt($_POST["pas"], "MiO1!");
```

validation.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) 
{
$password=crypt($_POST["password"], "MiO1!");
}


$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


if($query->rowCount() == 0)
{
header('Location: login.php?err=1');
}
```

another method(same problem)

```
if( crypt($_POST["pas"], "TmP2!") != $row["password"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `crypt` function only uses the first eight characters, that's by design (http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php).

You should use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead when storing a password in the database and use [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to compare it to the password the user entered:

```
if (password_verify($_POST["pas"], $row["password"]))
```

(this code won't work for you right now, since you have `crypt`-hashed passwords in your DB, you will have to re-hash them using `password_hash`)

Comment: oic,thankyou!
Now I know why my code cant work properly...
im going to learn password_hash now

Comment: *"only uses the first eight characters"* – **unless you explicitly specify another algorithm that uses more.**

Answer (score -1):

The thing is your code here is wrong `$password=crypt($_POST["password"], "MiO1!");` it will return a different set of string. the proper thing to use is the `has_equals` function. here is a sample provided by php documentation.

```
if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
//your query here;}
```

Comment: so i just need to change $password=crypt($_POST["password"], "MiO1!");  to if (hash_equals($hashed_password, crypt($user_input, $hashed_password))) {
??

Comment: sorry,im not good in php.I cant understand the code you provided

Comment: I have try this code,but still same valid until 7 character

Comment: if (hash_equals($row["password"], crypt($_POST["pas"], "MiO1!")))